# Deserializing JSON into C# Product ID with Shopify API

Tags: c#, json, shopify, deserialization

Hi I am trying to deserialize this json. And my application does not do it for me.

i am using c#

any suggestion?  thanks

this way i try to deserialize

```
            var deserialize = resultado.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<product>(deserialize);
```

json received

```html
{"product":{"id":6979552313549,"title":"Balance 100% Whey Protein 2.8kg w\/ FREE Magnesium complete powder","body_html":"Mountaineering backpack","vendor":"Balance","product_type":"physical","created_at":"2022-05-16T17:41:57-06:00","handle":"balance-100-whey-protein-2-8kg-w-free-magnesium-complete-powder-1","updated_at":"2022-05-26T12:34:07-06:00","published_at":"2022-05-16T17:41:57-06:00","template_suffix":null,"status":"active","published_scope":"web","tags":"Protein Powders, Specials, Stacks and Packs, Whey Protein Blend (WPI\/WPC)","admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/6979552313549","variants":[{"id":40875072585933,"product_id":6979552313549,"title":"Default Title","price":"700.00","sku":"","position":1,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":null,"fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"Default Title","option2":null,"option3":null,"created_at":"2022-05-26T12:34:07-06:00","updated_at":"2022-05-26T12:34:07-06:00","taxable":true,"barcode":null,"grams":0,"image_id":null,"weight":0.0,"weight_unit":"kg","inventory_item_id":42969806831821,"inventory_quantity":0,"old_inventory_quantity":0,"requires_shipping":true,"admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/40875072585933"}],"options":[{"id":8937193341133,"product_id":6979552313549,"name":"Title","position":1,"values":["Default Title"]}],"images":[{"id":30230589407437,"product_id":6979552313549,"position":1,"created_at":"2022-05-26T12:34:07-06:00","updated_at":"2022-05-26T12:34:07-06:00","alt":null,"width":2862,"height":2143,"src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0618\/4189\/9725\/products\/Definici_C3_B3n-del-producto-y-servicio_0bf23268-fee3-4b3b-a577-aeaa2336d6fc.png?v=1653590047","variant_ids":[],"admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/30230589407437"}],"image":{"id":30230589407437,"product_id":6979552313549,"position":1,"created_at":"2022-05-26T12:34:07-06:00","updated_at":"2022-05-26T12:34:07-06:00","alt":null,"width":2862,"height":2143,"src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0618\/4189\/9725\/products\/Definici_C3_B3n-del-producto-y-servicio_0bf23268-fee3-4b3b-a577-aeaa2336d6fc.png?v=1653590047","variant_ids":[],"admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/30230589407437"}}}
```

If I have a Model class called "Product"

```
public class product
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string body_html { get; set; }
    public string vendor { get; set; }
    public string product_type { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public string handle { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime published_at { get; set; }
    public object template_suffix { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string published_scope { get; set; }
    public string tags { get; set; }
    public string admin_graphql_api_id { get; set; }
    public List<Models.Producto.Variant> variants { get; set; }
    public List<Models.Producto.Option> options { get; set; }
    public List<Models.Producto.Images> images { get; set; }
    public Models.Producto.Image image { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your post is missing Important Information. Also, what does *`does not do it for me`* mean?  If you are getting an exception tell us what it is.

Comment: @CarlosTeleguario It deserializes fine for me using your example class, but I changed the last 3 properties to `List<object>` and the final property as `object` since you didn't provide those classes in your post.

Comment: @CarlosTeleguario Also, `List<Models.Producto.Images>`? Do you have a model class called `Images` as well? Because your last property is `Models.Producto.Image`. Or is this just a typo?

Comment: yes, I have all the classes

Comment: Please post those as well. Also, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I can't add all the classes Stack Overflow doesn't allow me, it tells me that it's a lot of code.

Comment: var deserialize =
productId.json is correct..

var a= null

Comment: All you need is to post a json that your api sends. We don't need your classes, we will create the classes you need  for you

Comment: By the way `ReadAsStringAsync().Result` is a bad idea, better to use `await ... ReadAsStringAsync()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you are using a wrong class to deserialize json, should be

```
var data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

main classes (I highly recommend you to use a Pascal style for property names)

```
    public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("product")]
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Product
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("body_html")]
        public string BodyHtml { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("vendor")]
        public string Vendor { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("product_type")]
        public string ProductType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("created_at")]
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("handle")]
        public string Handle { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("updated_at")]
        public DateTimeOffset UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("published_at")]
        public DateTimeOffset PublishedAt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("template_suffix")]
        public object TemplateSuffix { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("published_scope")]
        public string PublishedScope { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tags")]
        public string Tags { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("admin_graphql_api_id")]
        public string AdminGraphqlApiId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("variants")]
        public List<Variant> Variants { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("options")]
        public List<Option> Options { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("images")]
        public List<Image> Images { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("image")]
        public Image Image { get; set; }
    }
```

other classes

```
    public partial class Image
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("product_id")]
        public long ProductId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("position")]
        public long Position { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("created_at")]
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("updated_at")]
        public DateTimeOffset UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("alt")]
        public object Alt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("width")]
        public long Width { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("height")]
        public long Height { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("src")]
        public Uri Src { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("variant_ids")]
        public List<object> VariantIds { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("admin_graphql_api_id")]
        public string AdminGraphqlApiId { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Option
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("product_id")]
        public long ProductId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("position")]
        public long Position { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("values")]
        public List<string> Values { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Variant
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("product_id")]
        public long ProductId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("price")]
        public string Price { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sku")]
        public string Sku { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("position")]
        public long Position { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("inventory_policy")]
        public string InventoryPolicy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("compare_at_price")]
        public object CompareAtPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fulfillment_service")]
        public string FulfillmentService { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("inventory_management")]
        public string InventoryManagement { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("option1")]
        public string Option1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("option2")]
        public object Option2 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("option3")]
        public object Option3 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("created_at")]
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("updated_at")]
        public DateTimeOffset UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("taxable")]
        public bool Taxable { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("barcode")]
        public object Barcode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("grams")]
        public long Grams { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("image_id")]
        public object ImageId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("weight")]
        public long Weight { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("weight_unit")]
        public string WeightUnit { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("inventory_item_id")]
        public long InventoryItemId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("inventory_quantity")]
        public long InventoryQuantity { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("old_inventory_quantity")]
        public long OldInventoryQuantity { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("requires_shipping")]
        public bool RequiresShipping { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("admin_graphql_api_id")]
        public string AdminGraphqlApiId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks if it helped me, My Get product list now does not work, it is correct that I add public List<Product> list { get; set; }, and what is its Json property?

Comment: @CarlosTeleguario Where  in the code did you add list property? JsonProperty doesn't affect anything in your code, it just maps a json name to a c# property name.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
var response =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<<string, string>>(deserialize);
    
string value =  response["key"];
```

Comment: No. This will not fix the problem.

Comment: If you switch to `Dictionary<string, object>`, then it will deserialize. Your current solution causes a parser error.

Comment: no, it didn't work for me